# Difference between connect() and connect_object() in pygtk

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I am using pygtk. I am not getting what is the difference between connect() and connect_object() in pygtk. Can somebody clarify me on this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained [here](http://pygstdocs.berlios.de/pygobject-reference/class-gobject.html#method-gobject--connect-object), `connect_object` is used to replace the object passed to the callback method by default (which is the one that emitted the signal).

For example,

```
>>> label = gtk.Label()
>>> button = gtk.Button()
>>> def callback(obj):
...    print obj
>>> button.connect('clicked', callback)  # button will be passed by default
>>> button.emit('clicked')
<gtk.Button object at 0x27cd870 (GtkButton at 0x22c6190)>
>>> button.disconnect_by_func(callback)
>>> button.connect_object('clicked', callback, label)  # label will be passed instead of button
>>> button.emit('clicked')
<gtk.Label object at 0x27cd9b0 (GtkLabel at 0x22b64f0)>
```

Note: Usually in callback methods, you'll be interested in the object that emitted the signal (the one passed by default), so `connect_object` isn't used frequently.

Edit: In addition to this, you'll find [here](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/sec-TheoryOfSignalsAndCallbacks.html) the following explanation:

> `connect_object()` allows the PyGTK widget methods that only take a single argument (self) to be used as signal handlers.

Comment: can you also let me know how PyGTK widget methods that only take a single argument (self) to be used as signal handlers using connect_object() ?

Comment: Sorry, the previous example would be more like this: `button.connect_object('clicked', gtk.Label.show, label)`.